# Accurate method to calculate double FMA and Shared memory latency

Tags: cuda, latency, microbenchmark, gpu-shared-memory, fma

I am trying to come up with an accurate way to measure the latency of two operations:

1. Latency of a double precision FMA operation.
2. Latency of a double precision load from shared memory.

I am using a K20x and was wondering if this code would give accurate measurements.

```
#include <cuda.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Clock rate
#define MHZ 732e6
//number of streaming multiprocessors
#define SMS 14
// number of double precision units
#define DP_UNITS 16*4
//number of shared banks
#define SHARED_BANKS 32

#define ITER 100000
#define NEARONE 1.0000000000000004

__global__ void fma_latency_kernal(double *in, double *out){
  int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  double val = in[tid];
#pragma unroll 100
  for(int i=0; i<ITER; i++){
    val+=val*NEARONE;
  }
  out[tid]=val;
}

__global__ void shared_latency_kernel(double *in, double *out){
  volatile extern __shared__ double smem[];
  int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  smem[threadIdx.x]=in[tid];
#pragma unroll 32
  for(int i=0; i<ITER; i++){
    smem[threadIdx.x]=smem[(threadIdx.x+i)%32]*NEARONE;
  }
  out[tid]=smem[threadIdx.x];
}

int main (int argc , char **argv){

  float time;
  cudaEvent_t start, stop, start2, stop2;

  double *d_A, *d_B;
  cudaMalloc(&d_A, DP_UNITS*SMS*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_B, DP_UNITS*SMS*sizeof(float));

  cudaError_t err;

  cudaEventCreate(&start);
  cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

  fma_latency_kernal<<<SMS, DP_UNITS>>>(d_A, d_B);

  cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
  time/=1000;
  err = cudaGetLastError();
  if(err!=cudaSuccess)
    printf("Error FMA: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
  printf("Latency of FMA = %3.1f clock cycles\n", (time/(double)ITER)*(double)MHZ);


  cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig(cudaSharedMemBankSizeFourByte);
  cudaEventCreate(&start2);
  cudaEventCreate(&stop2);
  cudaEventRecord(start2, 0);

  shared_latency_kernel<<<1, SHARED_BANKS, sizeof(double)>>>(d_A, d_B );

  cudaEventRecord(stop2, 0);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop2);
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start2, stop2);
  time/=1000;
  err = cudaGetLastError();
  if(err!=cudaSuccess)
    printf("Error Shared Memory: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));

  printf("Latency of Shared Memory = %3.1f clock cycles\n", time/(double)ITER*(double)MHZ);

}
```

My results on the K20x are the following:

1. Latency of FMA = 16.4 clock cycles
2. Latency of Shared Memory = 60.7 clock cycles

This seems reasonable to me, but I am not sure how accurate it is.

Comment: Your results appear to be in the ballpark but a bit high. You may need to refine your methodology slightly. Based on my performance optimization efforts, I would suggest oversubscribing the SMs by about 20x, that is, run 20 times more threads than can physically run concurrently. This reduces the impact of various overheads in the GPU, showing steady-state performance. You may be interested in previous micro-benchmarking studies: [2010 paper](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~myrto/gpuarch-ispass2010.pdf), [2014 poster](http://lpgpu.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/poster_andresch_acaces2014.pdf)

Comment: While your current code wouldn't seem to be affected, here is a small caveat: The instruction cache size on GPUs is small, in the 4KB to 8KB range I think. The instructions are large (typically comprising 8 bytes). There is no branch prediction. This means that unrolled loops that get so large that they cannot completely fit into the instruction cache will experience a compulsory ICache miss when they encounter the loop-closing branch. From my experiments this can result in a performance loss of around 3% (this obviously differs based on code context and probably differs by GPU architecture).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will try playing with the unroll. I am not sure how to measure latency while oversubscribing the SM's. If I start sending many warps to the SM's they will start overlapping execution of the instructions. How do you back out the latency in this case? Or are you suggesting that I set the shared memory to limit the execution to one warp at a time?

Answer (score 2):

Your latency values look very high to me - nearly double what I'd expect. To measure how many cycles something takes on the GPU, you can insert clock() functions before and after the relevant part of the kernel function. The clock function returns the current cycle as an int, so by subtracting the first value from the second you get the the number of cycles that passed between dispatching the first clock instruction and dispatching the second clock instruction.

Note that the numbers you get from this method will include extra time from the clock instructions themselves; I believe that by default a thread will block for several cycles immediately before and after every clock instruction, so you may want to experiment with that to see how many cycles it's adding so you can subtract them back out.